# How to set default product type in WooCommerce to External/Affiliate

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic

I've been struggling to set the default product type in WooCommerce to be "External/Affiliate". I tried every line of code I found in this forum but none of them seem to be working.

Previously, a plugin like [Remove tabs and fields from WooCommerce](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wc-remove-tabs-and-fields/) can to the job but it hasn't been updated for over a year and there is a vulnerability issue.

If anyone knows how to set the default product type to External/Affiliate, I'll be forever grateful.

[image]